# Controlling VI inside of Project from Python via COM/ActiveX

Tags: python, com, activex, labview

From [NI-Site:](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000015BKpSAM&l=de-DE)

```
labview = win32com.client.Dispatch("Labview.Application")
VI = labview.getvireference(r'c:\TEMP\ctrl\ctrl.vi')
print(f'Name: {VI.Name}')
print(VI.getcontrolvalue('main'))
```

This is working perfectly fine as long as my VI is not inside of a project. I have a running VI inside a project however and want to read/write control values from python. There are no errors but python reads/writes to a seperate instance of the VI which is outside of the project. Can I modify the path to the VI so python acesses the instance inside the project?

How to reproduce:

1. Python Script

   ```py
   from icecream import ic
   import win32com.client
   import time
   import numpy as np

   class LabView():
       def __init__(self,vi):
           self.LabVIEW    = win32com.client.Dispatch("Labview.Application")
           self.VI         = self.LabVIEW.getvireference(vi)
       def set_potential(self,potential):
           ic(potential)
           self.VI.SetControlValue("Set Potential",potential)  


   vi = r'C:\path...\testProject\test.vi'
   lab = LabView(vi)


   while True:
       lab.set_potential(np.random.uniform(-2,2))
       time.sleep(3)
   ```
2. [Place VI inside of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAVXq.png)
3. Open and run VI outside of project and start python script -> works
4. Open and run VI from Project Explorer and start python script -> does not work

Comment: Could you share your project's structure? I made quick test - and in my case everything works. I have VI which is part of the project. When VI is running, python code reads indicator value nicely.

Comment: I have added a picture of the structure. I can simultaneously open two instances of the same VI, one inside the project one outside. How does Python know which instance it should reference?

Comment: I believe that Python does not care from where VI is launched. I did simple test - created project, added there VI, saved project. Opened VI from project, launched it - and then executed python script. And it captured exactly that particular VI. And how do you know, that python reads/writes another instance of the VI?

Comment: I have a small script which sets a control value to a random value every second. When I open the VI outside the project, I can see the value changing (when its running and also when not). Then I close this VI and open the project. Start the VI from the Project Explorer and the value isn't changing.

Comment: @kosist would you mind sharing your simple test? I tried to recreate it and it has the same problem as my main project

Comment: Here you go: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/314103990ec649df8bd76dae03e4ec7320211126111937/649bd4

Comment: @kosist I have the same issue here. Running it outside the project results in random readings from the VI (expected). If i run it inside the project, python gets the same value over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider just building a vi you can call via the [G-CLI tool](https://github.com/JamesMc86/G-CLI)(windows only currently) and then interfacing though that command line from python.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30700211)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some idea on how to do this . I have had sucess with this . You have to use OpenProject active x method  to get reference to project and then use the project.Application to get reference to the Application in context of the project. From then on, it works similar as if you are communicating with non project VI's i.e replace the win32com.client.Dispatch("Labview.Application") reference with proj.Application

```
class LabView():
    def __init__(self,project_path=''): #vi path 
        self.LabVIEW_Top    = win32com.client.Dispatch("Labview.Application")
        self.LabVIEW=self.LabVIEW_Top #init as if there is no project
        if project_path !='' :# project path was provided
            self.LabVIEW_Top._FlagAsMethod('OpenProject')
            proj=self.LabVIEW_Top.OpenProject(project_path)
            self.LabVIEW=proj.Application #over ride to project application
```